# When can you unlock Shotguns?

Tags: blacklight-retribution

I've been playing for a little while and I'm only level 5. I've been killed a few times by people using Shotguns but I can't buy any of them yet. At what level can I unlock them without paying Zen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shotgun receiver is unlocked at level 20.